# State not update when using setter and setInterval in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I have the following code, which I expect it to print an extra 10 every 2 seconds on the screen. However, it only prints 10 once. `console.log(digits)` gave me the correct array of 10s. How can I add a 10 to the array every 2 seconds and print the updated array on the screen each time the 10 is added?

Code sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-https-zk58p?file=/src/App.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
let data = [];
export default function App() {
  const [digits, setDigits] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    let timer = setInterval(() => {
      data.push(10);
      setDigits(data);
      console.log(digits);
    }, 2000);
    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }, [digits]);

  return <div className="App">{digits}</div>;
}
```

Comment: Its because of `setDigits(data);` With arrays do it `setDigits([...data]);`. Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-kapitsa-cp5qf?file=/src/App.js OR better yet, remove the `data` ant just do `let timer = setInterval(() => { setDigits([...digits, 10]); }, 2000);`

Comment: @Lith can you provide an answer with explanations so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with `setDigits(data)`. With arrays, you should be executing `setDigits([...data])`.

Another way would be doing this:

```
let timer = setInterval(() => { 
    setDigits([...digits, 10]); 
}, 2000);
```

Whenever dealing with objects, you should treat them as immutables. What happened here is you modifying an array and puhsing the SAME array into a state. While the value might be different, the array is actually the same hence it does not update the render. Whenever doing `[...data]` it creates a new array with the same values hence trigger the update.

`useEffect` picks up the new value change hence why it fires again(cant be observed by `console.log()`), but this does not trigger re-render of the component.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are mutating the same array `data` by pushing `10` after each `2` seconds. As a result, the `useEffect` is not executing in the subsequent renders. So either you spread `data` array as in the following code snippet or simply get rid of the `data` variable and rely on `digits` array as Lith suggested.

```
export default function App() {
  const [digits, setDigits] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    let timer = setInterval(() => {
      data = [...data, 10];
      setDigits(data);
      console.log(digits);
    }, 2000);
    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }, [digits]);

  return <div className="App">{digits}</div>;
}
```

Comment: But the content of `data` changes after every 2 seconds, I included it in the dependency array, why does `useEffect` not pick the change up?

Comment: Yes, it changes. But `push` modifies the same array, which results in the same reference. Which is the opposite in the case of `concat` or `[...]`.